# ionic cannot use IonicStorageModule in LoginComponent

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

i'm using IonicStorage for storing credentials locally. In My app.compoent its working fine. Afterwards i created a new component using ionic generate, afterwards i wrote this code:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastController: ToastController, private router: Router,
          private storage: Storage) { }

 private storeData() {

// @ts-ignore
this.storage.set('email', this.login.email);
// @ts-ignore
this.storage.set('pw', this.login.pw);
this.storage.set('lastlogin', Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000));
```

}

here is my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   entryComponents: [],
   imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
             IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
            HttpClientModule, FormsModule
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
       SplashScreen,
       { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
 export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Could you please include the imports from your login component?

Comment: yep that was the issue thank you

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, I had the same issue sooo many times! Would you mind adding that as an answer and accept it in order to close this question? :)